# Remove label text without removing text box within label

Tags: html, css, forms, css-selectors, label

## What I have:

I have a login form with username and password text box fields. The fields are wrapped in labels.

## What I need:

I need to remove the text of the labels because I want to apply placeholder values instead.

## My code:

Note: I've managed to target the breaks but can't target the rendered text of the labels.

```css
label[for=user_login] > br,
label[for=user_pass] > br {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<p>
  <label for="user_login">Username
    <br>
    <input type="text" name="log" id="user_login" class="input" value="" size="20">
  </label>
</p>
<p>
  <label for="user_pass">Password
    <br>
    <input type="password" name="pwd" id="user_pass" class="input" value="" size="20">
  </label>
</p>
```

I require a CSS-based solution. Editing the mark-up is not an option.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i have tried to give a solution according what you said above....

What i did is:

> I have shifted the label text (with **TEXT-INDENT** property) and removed extra spances around **"P"** tag so that text will not appear and space
>   also will not be there, you can only see the textbox as you wanted.

Hope this helps you.

so your code will be like this:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
     <title></title>
     <style type="text/css">
      label[for=user_login] > br,
      label[for=user_pass] > br {
       display: none;
      }
      label {
       text-indent: 9999px;
       width: 100%;
       display: block;
       overflow: hidden;
      }
      p {
       margin: 0;
       padding: 0;
      }
     </style>
    </head>
    <body>
     <p>
      <label for="user_login">Username
       <br>
       <input type="text" name="log" id="user_login" class="input" value="" size="20">
      </label>
     </p>
     <p>
      <label for="user_pass">Password
       <br>
       <input type="password" name="pwd" id="user_pass" class="input" value="" size="20">
      </label>
     </p>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: This is a more universal solution that applies unilaterally to all fields without depending on pixel counting. Thanks for the work-around.

Comment: @ClarusDignus thank you ... :) and you are most welcome

Answer (score 5):

Add this property on particular label class

```
label {
   color: transparent;
}
```

Or create class for specific label and add this class on label

```
.txtlbl label{
    color: transparent;
}
```

Comment: What of the **space** the being occupied by the text? Your solution conceals the characters but not the space. Surely there's a CSS selector that will actually remove the text completely.

Comment: label{
 color: transparent;
 margin-left: -69px;
    position: relative;
}

Comment: It works providing I calculate the pixel width of the text for the label text of each field but feels a little hackish. I was hoping for a selector that will allow me to set the text value to none however in lieu of this, your solution appears to be the only step forward. Thanks for your time.

Comment: Because you are using label and input both in one label class , so needs to separate both. :)

Answer (score 1):

Another idea...You could have the input field lay overtop of the label.  This will mitigate potential accessibility issues such as discoverability, screen reader "focus", and possible scrolling caused by moving the label text offscreen when using a screen-reader or switch device.

```css
[for^=user_] > br {
  display: none;
}
[for^=user_] {
  position: relative;
}
input[id^=user_] {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  margin: 0; //solve for Safari showing a bit of text due to 2px default margin
}
```

```html
<p>
  <label for="user_login">Username
    <br>
    <input type="text" name="log" id="user_login" class="input" value="" size="20">
  </label>
</p>
<p>
  <label for="user_pass">Password
    <br>
    <input type="password" name="pwd" id="user_pass" class="input" value="" size="20">
  </label>
</p>
```

Comment: Thanks for this alternative concept. What is the name of the up arrow you're using? I'd like to know the terminology of the selector to research what browsers support it.

Comment: It means anything that starts with.  You can use $= for anything that ends with, etc.

Comment: Here's a great CSS-Tricks article on different attribute selectors: https://css-tricks.com/attribute-selectors/

Comment: It's well-supported on older browser: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_attr_begin.asp. I'll trial implementation in a hour or so.

Comment: Very good support for query selectors.  IE 7 and 8 recognize [attr^=val], [attr$=val], and [attr*=val].  IE9+ and all other browsers have full query support. http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-sel3

Answer (score 0):

as for your situation that you can't edit the markup, what you can do is just give the input a
 `margin-left -85px;`
 so it covers the label and there is no space of where the label was.